# Data frame Manipulation and conversions

Tags: r

I have about 150 rainfall stations in the following format;
The first row is years and the second row is months 1-12 repeating for each year.

Data Frame:

```
1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1989,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
11.8,0,0,3.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4.4,0,2.1,4.5,0,0,0,0,47.9,3.6,15.1,45.3,3,0,36.8,0,0,0,0,0,1.3,0,0,10
5.2,0,0,0,2.2,0,0,0,0,2.7,0,0,0,3.2,0,3.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.8,12.8
7.1,0,0,11.3,4,0,0,0,0,8.2,0,0.9,0,0,47.2,11.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10.9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31.7,8.3,0,5.3,0,40.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.4,11.7,0
0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,3.3,6.1,0,6.9,0,1.5,2.3,5.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.1,0,0,0,7,4.6,0,0,26.6,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.5,0,0,0,0,2.7,0,33.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,37.3
0,0,0,12,7.3,0,0,0,0,0,8.5,0,0,1.8,0,1.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.3
0,0,0,5.2,1.6,0,0,6.7,0,0,0,8.6,0,0,17.2,3.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,7.3,0
0,0,12,24.9,12,0,0,0,0,3.3,0,3.2,0,2.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4.3
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2.4,0,5.8,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,11.7,42
0,0,0,3.2,0,0,0,17.6,0,0,0,0,0,7.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9.1,15,0
0,0,2.2,0,7,0,0,0,0,5.8,48.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.2,0
0,0,29.6,9.7,4,0,0,3,0,0,3.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2.1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1.8,8.7,3,0,0,0,42.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,9.8,0,0
6.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.6,0,2,0,0,22.8,9,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12.2,0,0,0,0,4.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16.5
0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,7.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25.4,0,0,43.5,3.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,28.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.8,12,0,0,17.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,8,0,20.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.9,0,1.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.2,2.4,0,0,7.2,7.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23.9,1.6,1.8,0,3.2,0,8.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,15,7.1,0,0,0,0,10.4,0,0,0,15.9,0,14.3,0,0,0,0,0,3.3,0,0
0,0,16.1,0,0,0,0,0.9,0,7.3,14.5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14.3,28.8,12.7,19.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.1,0,7.2,0
0,,0,32.3,0,0,0,0,0,15.3,0,5.1,0,,0,0,4.1,0,0,0,0,10.9,27.8,0
0,,0,3.3,0,0,0,0.9,0,1.8,7.1,18.5,0,,0,0,0,0,0,39,7.8,0,19.3,10
0,,0,,0,,0,0,,7.4,,4.3,5,,0,,0,,0,0,,25.4,,0
```

I want to convert this data into the following format;

```
Year,Day,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
1989,1,11.8,0,0,3.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1989,2,4.4,0,2.1,4.5,0,0,0,0,47.9,3.6,15.1,45.3
1989,3,5.2,0,0,0,2.2,0,0,0,0,2.7,0,0
1989,4,7.1,0,0,11.3,4,0,0,0,0,8.2,0,0.9
1989,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31.7,8.3,0,5.3
1989,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,3.3,6.1,0,6.9
1989,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.1,0,0,0
1989,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.5,0,0,0
1989,9,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.2,0
1989,10,0,0,0,12,7.3,0,0,0,0,0,8.5,0
1989,11,0,0,0,5.2,1.6,0,0,6.7,0,0,0,8.6
1989,12,0,0,12,24.9,12,0,0,0,0,3.3,0,3.2
1989,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2.4
1989,14,0,0,0,3.2,0,0,0,17.6,0,0,0,0
1989,15,0,0,2.2,0,7,0,0,0,0,5.8,48.8,0
1989,16,0,0,29.6,9.7,4,0,0,3,0,0,3.6,0
1989,17,2.1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1.8,8.7,3,0,0
1989,18,6.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.6,0,2
1989,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12.2,0
1989,20,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1989,21,0,0,7.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25.4,0
1989,22,0,0,28.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.8,12
1989,23,0,8,0,20.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.9,0
1989,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.2,2.4
1989,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23.9,1.6,1.8
1989,26,0,0,0,15,7.1,0,0,0,0,10.4,0,0
1989,27,0,0,16.1,0,0,0,0,0.9,0,7.3,14.5,0
1989,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14.3,28.8,12.7,19.2,0
1989,29,0,,0,32.3,0,0,0,0,0,15.3,0,5.1
1989,30,0,,0,3.3,0,0,0,0.9,0,1.8,7.1,18.5
1989,31,0,,0,,0,,0,0,,7.4,,4.3
1990,1,1.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,2,3,0,36.8,0,0,0,0,0,1.3,0,0,10
1990,3,0,3.2,0,3.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.8,12.8
1990,4,0,0,47.2,11.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10.9
1990,5,0,40.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.4,11.7,0
1990,6,0,1.5,2.3,5.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,7,7,4.6,0,0,26.6,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
1990,8,0,2.7,0,33.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,9,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,37.3
1990,10,0,1.8,0,1.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.3
1990,11,0,0,17.2,3.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,7.3,0
1990,12,0,2.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4.3
1990,13,0,5.8,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,11.7,42
1990,14,0,7.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9.1,15,0
1990,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.2,0
1990,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,17,0,42.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,9.8,0,0
1990,18,0,0,22.8,9,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0
1990,19,0,0,0,4.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16.5
1990,20,21.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,21,0,43.5,3.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,22,0,0,17.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,23,1.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,24,0,0,7.2,7.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,25,0,3.2,0,8.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,26,0,15.9,0,14.3,0,0,0,0,0,3.3,0,0
1990,27,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1990,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.1,0,7.2,0
1990,29,0,,0,0,4.1,0,0,0,0,10.9,27.8,0
1990,30,0,,0,0,0,0,0,39,7.8,0,19.3,10
1990,31,5,,0,,0,,0,0,,25.4,,0
```

I have created this format manually in the spreadsheet but the process is very tedious and time consuming I will need a month to prepare all the data. The required format may not necessarily contain the naming "Jan","Feb" etc it may remain with the original Numbers 1-12 will be enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I only have the data frame in .csv format, I did the sample conversing by transpose function in excel.

Comment: It looks like you just want to transpose your data. use `t(youdata)` to see if that looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could read the data with `read.csv` and specify `header = FALSE`.  Then, create a grouping column based on the second rows i.e. month row for `split`ting the dataset into a `list` of data.frames.  Loop over the `list`, change the column names with the second row (`row_to_names` - from `janitor`), create 'Year' column as the `first` value from any of the column, remove the first row (`slice(-1)`), create the 'Day' column as 'row_number`and then bind the`list `elements (`bind_rows`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(unlist(df1[2,])) < 0))

out <- split.default(df1, grp) %>%
       map(~ .x %>%
           row_to_names(2, remove_rows_above = FALSE) %>%
           rename_all(~ month.abb[as.integer(.)]) %>%
           mutate(Year = first(.[[1]])) %>%
           slice(-1) %>% 
           mutate(Day = row_number())) %>%
        bind_rows %>%
        select(Year, Day, everything())
    

head(out)
#  Year Day  Jan Feb Mar  Apr May Jun Jul Aug  Sep Oct  Nov  Dec
#1 1989   1 11.8   0 0.0  3.3 0.0   0   0   0  0.0 0.0  0.0  0.0
#2 1989   2  4.4   0 2.1  4.5 0.0   0   0   0 47.9 3.6 15.1 45.3
#3 1989   3  5.2   0 0.0  0.0 2.2   0   0   0  0.0 2.7  0.0  0.0
#4 1989   4  7.1   0 0.0 11.3 4.0   0   0   0  0.0 8.2  0.0  0.9
#5 1989   5  0.0   0 0.0  0.0 0.0   0   0   0 31.7 8.3  0.0  5.3
#6 1989   6  0.0   0 0.0 12.0 0.0   0   0   0  3.3 6.1  0.0  6.9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', header = FALSE)

df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1989, 1, 11.8, 4.4, 5.2, 7.1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1, 6.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V2 = c(1989L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA), V3 = c(1989, 3, 0, 2.1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 2.2, 29.6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7.6, 28.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 16.1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(1989, 4, 3.3, 4.5, 0, 11.3, 
0, 12, 0, 0, 25, 12, 5.2, 24.9, 0, 3.2, 0, 9.7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
0, 20.6, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 32.3, 3.3, NA), V5 = c(1989, 5, 0, 0, 
2.2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.3, 1.6, 12, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V6 = c(1989L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), V7 = c(1989L, 
7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), V8 = c(1989, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.7, 0, 0, 17.6, 
0, 3, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 14.3, 0, 0.9, 0), 
    V9 = c(1989, 9, 0, 47.9, 0, 0, 31.7, 3.3, 5.1, 6.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.8, 
    0, 0, NA), V10 = c(1989, 10, 0, 3.6, 2.7, 8.2, 8.3, 6.1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.3, 2, 0, 5.8, 0, 3, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 23.9, 10.4, 7.3, 12.7, 15.3, 1.8, 7.4), V11 = c(1989, 
    11, 0, 15.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 8.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48.8, 
    3.6, 0, 0, 12.2, 0, 25.4, 1.8, 1.9, 6.2, 1.6, 0, 14.5, 19.2, 
    0, 7.1, NA), V12 = c(1989, 12, 0, 45.3, 0, 0.9, 5.3, 6.9, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 8.6, 3.2, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 
    2.4, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 5.1, 18.5, 4.3), V13 = c(1990, 1, 1.8, 
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21.9, 
    0, 0, 1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5), V14 = c(1990, 2, 0, 0, 
    3.2, 0, 40.4, 1.5, 4.6, 2.7, 0, 1.8, 0, 2.5, 5.8, 7.3, 0, 
    0, 42.7, 0, 0, 0, 43.5, 0, 0, 0, 3.2, 15.9, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA), V15 = c(1990, 3, 0, 36.8, 0, 47.2, 0, 2.3, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 17.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.8, 0, 0, 3.9, 17.7, 0, 7.2, 
    0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0), V16 = c(1990, 4, 0, 0, 3.9, 11.1, 0, 
    5.6, 0, 33.1, 4, 1.9, 3.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 4.4, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 7.5, 8.1, 14.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), V17 = c(1990, 5, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.1, 0, 0), V18 = c(1990L, 6L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    NA), V19 = c(1990L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V20 = c(1990L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L), V21 = c(1990, 
    9, 0, 1.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.1, 0, 7.8, NA), V22 = c(1990, 
    10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.1, 0, 0, 9.8, 
    4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.3, 0, 0, 10.9, 0, 25.4), V23 = c(1990, 
    11, 0, 0, 5.8, 0, 11.7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7.3, 0, 11.7, 15, 
    6.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.2, 27.8, 19.3, 
    NA), V24 = c(1990, 12, 0, 10, 12.8, 10.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37.3, 
    3.3, 0, 4.3, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 10, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your data without header, you can transpose it, get the data in long format, convert to month names, create a day number and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t(df) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = V3:V33, names_to = 'day') %>%
  mutate(V2 = month.abb[V2], 
         day = match(day, unique(day))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V2, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 62 x 14
#      V1   day   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1989     1  11.8     0   0     3.3   0       0     0     0   0     0     0     0  
# 2  1989     2   4.4     0   2.1   4.5   0       0     0     0  47.9   3.6  15.1  45.3
# 3  1989     3   5.2     0   0     0     2.2     0     0     0   0     2.7   0     0  
# 4  1989     4   7.1     0   0    11.3   4       0     0     0   0     8.2   0     0.9
# 5  1989     5   0       0   0     0     0       0     0     0  31.7   8.3   0     5.3
# 6  1989     6   0       0   0    12     0       0     0     0   3.3   6.1   0     6.9
# 7  1989     7   0       0   0     0     0       0     0     0   5.1   0     0     0  
# 8  1989     8   0       0   0     0     0       0     0     0   6.5   0     0     0  
# 9  1989     9   0       0   0    25     0       0     0     0   0     0     2.2   0  
#10  1989    10   0       0   0    12     7.3     0     0     0   0     0     8.5   0  
# … with 52 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1989, 1, 11.8, 4.4, 5.2, 7.1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1, 6.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V2 = c(1989L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA), V3 = c(1989, 3, 0, 2.1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 2.2, 29.6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7.6, 28.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 16.1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(1989, 4, 3.3, 4.5, 0, 11.3, 
0, 12, 0, 0, 25, 12, 5.2, 24.9, 0, 3.2, 0, 9.7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
0, 20.6, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 32.3, 3.3, NA), V5 = c(1989, 5, 0, 0, 
2.2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.3, 1.6, 12, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V6 = c(1989L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), V7 = c(1989L, 
7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), V8 = c(1989, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.7, 0, 0, 17.6, 
0, 3, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 14.3, 0, 0.9, 0), 
    V9 = c(1989, 9, 0, 47.9, 0, 0, 31.7, 3.3, 5.1, 6.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.8, 
    0, 0, NA), V10 = c(1989, 10, 0, 3.6, 2.7, 8.2, 8.3, 6.1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.3, 2, 0, 5.8, 0, 3, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 23.9, 10.4, 7.3, 12.7, 15.3, 1.8, 7.4), V11 = c(1989, 
    11, 0, 15.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 8.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48.8, 
    3.6, 0, 0, 12.2, 0, 25.4, 1.8, 1.9, 6.2, 1.6, 0, 14.5, 19.2, 
    0, 7.1, NA), V12 = c(1989, 12, 0, 45.3, 0, 0.9, 5.3, 6.9, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 8.6, 3.2, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 
    2.4, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 5.1, 18.5, 4.3), V13 = c(1990, 1, 1.8, 
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21.9, 
    0, 0, 1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5), V14 = c(1990, 2, 0, 0, 
    3.2, 0, 40.4, 1.5, 4.6, 2.7, 0, 1.8, 0, 2.5, 5.8, 7.3, 0, 
    0, 42.7, 0, 0, 0, 43.5, 0, 0, 0, 3.2, 15.9, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA), V15 = c(1990, 3, 0, 36.8, 0, 47.2, 0, 2.3, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 17.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.8, 0, 0, 3.9, 17.7, 0, 7.2, 
    0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0), V16 = c(1990, 4, 0, 0, 3.9, 11.1, 0, 
    5.6, 0, 33.1, 4, 1.9, 3.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 4.4, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 7.5, 8.1, 14.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), V17 = c(1990, 5, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.1, 0, 0), V18 = c(1990L, 6L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    NA), V19 = c(1990L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V20 = c(1990L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L), V21 = c(1990, 
    9, 0, 1.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.1, 0, 7.8, NA), V22 = c(1990, 
    10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.1, 0, 0, 9.8, 
    4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.3, 0, 0, 10.9, 0, 25.4), V23 = c(1990, 
    11, 0, 0, 5.8, 0, 11.7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7.3, 0, 11.7, 15, 
    6.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.2, 27.8, 19.3, 
    NA), V24 = c(1990, 12, 0, 10, 12.8, 10.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37.3, 
    3.3, 0, 4.3, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 10, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```